# Using wix3 SqlScript to run generated temporary sql-script files

Tags: wix, wix3

I am starting to write an installer which will use the `SqlScript`-element.
That takes a reference to the `Binary`-table what script to run.

I would like to dynamically generate the script during the installation.

I can see three possibilities:

1. Somehow to get `SqlScript` to read it data from a file rather then a `Binary` entry.
2. Inject my generated script into the `Binary` table
3. Using SqlString
   Which will cause the need to place some rather long strings into `Properties`, but I guess that shouldn't really be a prolem.

Any advice?

Regards
*Leif*

(My reason, should anyone be interested is that the database should have a job set up, that calls on an installed exe-file. I prefer to create the job using sqlscript. And the path of that file is not known until InstallDir has been choosen.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way this is typically handled is to have the static stuff in SqlScript and use SqlString (which can contain formatted Properties) to execute the dynamic stuff. You can interleave the two with careful use of the Sequence attribute.